# Problem with creating view with multiple joins Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create a view that has **2 or more** *inner joins* in Datagrip with Postgres. First of all, the following query has no problem executing:

```
select *
from student inner join participates t on student.matrnr = t.matrnr
inner join martin_classes mc on t.lvnr = mc.lvnr;
```

And this would be a sort of an intermediate result, so that's why I want to create it as a view. But when I try to execute this query:

```
create view martin_andAll as
select *
from student inner join participates t on student.matrnr = t.matrnr
inner join martin_classes mc on t.lvnr = mc.lvnr;
```

the following error occurs: `[42701] ERROR: column "matrnr" specified more than once`
an easy fix would be using the keyword `USING` instead of `ON (condition)`
but that only works if I'm having only one join.
So at the following query I get the exact same error as before:

```
create view martin_andAll as
select *
from student inner join participates t using (matrnr)
inner join martin_classes mc using (lvnr);
```

And just to be clear, this works just fine:

```
create view martin_andAll as
select *
from student inner join participates t using (matrnr);
```

So my question is, why doesn't it work with multiple joins and how can I overcome this?

Comment: Don't use `select *`

Comment: Do NOT use `select *` - this is the cause of your error. NAME your required columns.

Comment: pff lol...thanks guys. I looked it up on many sites but couldn't figure it out. Many thanks!

Comment: Should I delete this?